# Reached bintray repository limit, and unable to delete published items older than 1 year

Tags: limit, bintray

I am using bintray for Open Source Projects, and hitting the repo limit (Not 100% sure since publishing error message is not clear)

When I tried to delete older versions of published libraries I was unable to... because they were too old...

Eventually deleted a newer version, and was able to publish...

Since storage is limited to 10GB and cleanup is limited to stuff published in the last year, my questions are:

- How can I get more storage?
- How can I delete stuff older than 1 year?

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase a [pro account](https://bintray.com/account/pricing?tab=account&type=pricing), but I would contact Bintray's support to address the storage issue as Bintray might support Open Source Projects.

An OSS user can't delete content that is older than 365 days, at least that is what the content [API says](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Bintray+REST+API#BintrayRESTAPI-DeleteContent). I guess this is to prevent users from deleting artifacts used by others who rely on your project.
However, you can delete a repository using the UI.

For more information see *Deleting Content under* [Managing Uploaded Content page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Managing+Uploaded+Content)

**Update:**
You can delete version older than 365 days using Bintray [Delete Version API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Bintray+REST+API#BintrayRESTAPI-DeleteVersion).

Comment: I succeeded in deleting a version that was more that a year old with this command: `curl -u <YOUR USER_NAME>:<YOUR API_KEY> -X DELETE https://api.bintray.com/packages/:subject/:repo/:package/versions/:version`